# How do I move around applications and bundle them in Ubuntu 18.04 application window?

Tags: startup-applications

[Ubuntu Application menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HyYF.png)

How do I move the applications around to different spots in the applications window? How do I join multiple applications into one app category like in the "Utilities" bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Try menulibre, a GUI menu editor available in Synaptic.  Its description says:

"An advanced menu editor that provides modern features in a clean, easy-to-use interface. All without GNOME dependencies, so even lightweight systems can benefit from the sanity that MenuLibre offers. MenuLibre is your one-stop shop for menus in Linux, whether you use GNOME, LXDE, Xfce, or Unity."

I use it and find it mostly effective, altho it seems to have some issues- for example, I'm not able to edit anything in the "other" directory.

I understand it's possible to edit the menu entries directly using .desktop files but I have not yet invested the time to figure that out - maybe somebody else will fill that in.